# Other programs are saying my USB drive is full but not really, folders automatically corrupted, etc

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a 1TB USB that I got about a month ago. It was working fine for 2 weeks until folders, when made, started getting corrupted automatically. All the other folders are fine except recently made ones.

Also, after the 2 weeks programs started saying the drive was full even though it had a lot more data left. (around 982GB?) The drive is formatted as exFAT, fyi.

Why has this happened? I think I need to restart the drive (Clears the drive, then resets it me thinks) but I don't know how. Any help?

(Info on the USB: It was bought from Amazon for around 10 - 15$. It doesn't have a case but it also hasn't been dropped, broken/deleted any files, etc. This USB should work like a charm but it doesn't.)

Edit: Currently copying files from the USB to C:/

Comment: Have you done a filesystem check on it?

Comment: Plug it in and run CHKDSK on the drive. If it does not come out error free from CHKDSK then it may be gone. It was an exceedingly cheap drive.

Comment: **1TB USB flash drive for that price is a fake!** It has way less than it is supposed to and that's why you see the error messages and data corruption.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is there any way to make the flash drive work properly?

Comment: No, of course not. Try to get your money back if possible. Denounce the fraud to Amazon so they can take down the listing.

Comment: What program tells you that the drive is full? Could you provide an example.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is likely correct.  It is probably a smaller drive that has been altered to look like a bigger one.

Comment: test it with https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3

Comment: Is it a USB hard drive or flash? If its flash its a scam for sure.

Comment: 1TB SSD or flash memories from any reputable manufacturer are around £150‐£200 ($210 ‐ $280) at the moment. You probably have a 64GB stick that has been messed around with. Even a spinning rust hard disk with 1TB would probably be more than you paid. We have a lot of "how they work" and "how to fix" type questions: https://superuser.com/search?q=fake+usb

Comment: @Mokubai  I got my WD Blue 1TB SSD for £87 inc VAT plus delivery a few months ago, they are £80.49 at the moment from a well known reputable supplier in the UK. They have PNY and Seagate ones cheaper.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey urfff... I've been staring at 2Tb drives. My bad. At any rate $15 is concerningly cheap for 1TB.

Comment: It's a fake. I have seen pictures of the inside of fake USB external hard drives with a small size flash memory card and a steel nut (for the weight) glued inside the case. The card would be modified to report a larger size. Like phishing emails, the ads catch the gullible or unwary.